# Passing additional parameters to be indexed as URL parameters

Tags: solr

Followup question from [Indexing office formats with a custom field type schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133491)

Uploading files to Solr is working.

I now need to pass additional parameters like 'modified' or 'mimetype' (as defined in the schema) as URL parameters. All examples use 'literal.id' for specifying the primary id
of each document. Additional parameters to be indexed must be prefixed with 'literal.' as well in order to be indexed properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order does not matter but they need to be prefixed by literal.

e.g. literal.title=Test

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=2&literal.title=Test&commit=true&fmap.content=text" -F "myfile=@1.pdf"
```